# How to set ItemsSource of DataGridTemplateColumn ComboBox in AutoGeneratingColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, combobox, datagridtemplatecolumn

I am trying to make an auto-generated GridView that will put an editable ComboBox in each cell in each column that contains strings. The selectable items for each column should match the values that are already in that column in the DataTable. I was hoping that something like the code below would work, but I cannot figure out how to set the ItemsSource of the ComboBox dynamically.

```
    private void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender,
            DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e) {
        if (e.PropertyType == typeof(string)) {
            DataGridTemplateColumn comboColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
            comboColumn.Header = e.PropertyName;
            comboColumn.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["ComboBoxDataTemplate"];
            //I'd like to do something like this:
            //comboColumn.ItemsSource = (DataContext as MainVM).PartClassVM.DataTable
                //.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row[e.PropertyName].ToString()).Distinct();
            e.Column = comboColumn;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone give me some pointers please?

EDIT: here is the XAML for the DataTemplate:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxDataTemplate">
        <ComboBox IsEditable="True" Margin="0" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Need to know the xaml for ComboBoxDataTemplate.  You need to locate the combobox inside the datatemplate, then you can set ItemsSource.

Comment: I've added the XAML for the DataTemplate. But how can I set the ItemsSource to a different list for each column?